# How to eliminate white space with Python string formatting (right justified)?

Tags: python

When using this code:

```
units = ['Temp [C]', 'v [m3/kg]', 'u [kJ/kg]', 's [kJ/kgK]', '[  new   ]']
data = ([1, 2, 1, 3,5], [0, 1, 0, 3, 5])

fmt_string = '{:>15}' * len(units)
print(fmt_string.format(*units))
for row in data:
    print(fmt_string.format(*row))
```

How can I eliminate the white spaces in front of the output so that it DOES NOT look like this:

[image: Incorrect Output]

And it WOULD look like this:

[image: Correct Output]

Ultimately I need the output (with more complex input) to look like this:

```
Temp [C]  v [m3/kg]  u [kJ/kg]  h [kJ/kg]  s [kJ/kgK]
     0.0  0.0009977       0.04       5.03      0.0001
    20.0  0.0009996      83.61      88.61      0.2954
    40.0  0.0010057     166.92     171.95      0.5705
    60.0  0.0010149     250.29     255.36      0.8287
    80.0  0.0010267     333.82     338.96      1.0723
   100.0  0.0010410     417.65     422.85      1.3034
   120.0  0.0010576     501.91     507.19      1.5236
   140.0  0.0010769     586.80     592.18      1.7344
   160.0  0.0010988     672.55     678.04      1.9374
   180.0  0.0011240     759.47     765.09      2.1338
   200.0  0.0011531     847.92     853.68      2.3251
   220.0  0.0011868     938.39     944.32      2.5127
   240.0  0.0012268    1031.60    1037.70      2.6983
   260.0  0.0012755    1128.50    1134.90      2.8841
```

Comment: what is the difference between input and output? Does the `Temp [C]` column have white spaces in it?

Comment: Does making `fmt_string = '{:>15}' * len(units)` less than 15 help? As in `fmt_string = '{:>12}' * len(units)`  for example

Comment: @quilicam please accept one of the answers as solution by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `units = [re.sub('\s+', '', u) for u in units]` to remove the whitespace of a string within a list, especially if the whitespace is within square brackets:

Your code:

```
units = ['Temp [C]', 'v [m3/kg]', 'u [kJ/kg]', 's [kJ/kgK]', '[  new   ]']
data = ([1, 2, 1, 3,5], [0, 1, 0, 3, 5])

fmt_string = '{:>15}' * len(units)
print(fmt_string.format(*units))
for row in data:
    print(fmt_string.format(*row))

Out[1]:
Temp [C]      v [m3/kg]      u [kJ/kg]     s [kJ/kgK]     [  new   ]
       1              2              1              3              5
       0              1              0              3              5
```

New Code (Notice the new output of "[new]" column):

```
units = [re.sub('\s+', '', u) for u in units]
fmt_string = '{:>15}' * len(units)
print(fmt_string.format(*units))
for row in data:
    print(fmt_string.format(*row))

Out[2]:
 Temp[C]       v[m3/kg]       u[kJ/kg]      s[kJ/kgK]          [new]
       1              2              1              3              5
       0              1              0              3              5
```